# mod_write infinite looping

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Trying to replace all instances of CMS_ with X. Only managed to get infinite loops so far.

```
Input: /mydir/?CMS_q=1&CMS_g=3 ...
Output: ?Xq=1&Xg=3 ...
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?mydir/(.+) $1                      [R]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)CMS_(.*?CMS_.*)$ $1X$2            [N,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)CMS_(.*)$ $1X$2               [L,R]
```

I had a working script a few years ago and lost it. I don't remember ever doing the "replace 1 at a time until 1 is left" business but I saw it suggested in a similar question. Can't seem to get it working regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't match against the query string in RewriteRule, which only matches against the URI. You can remove the CMS_ from the query string using this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)CMS_(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1X%2
```

Allowing this to loop will replace the **CMS_** with **X**, mod_rewrite will continue to loop through this until there are no more CMS_ in the query string. This is where the second rule comes in to play:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !CMS_
RewriteRule ^mydir/$ / [L,R]
```

First need to check to make sure there are no **CMS_** in the query string (otherwise the rule removing the **mydir** in front will be applied prematurely), then, remove the mydir in front. Also don't forget the `RewriteEngine On` before all of this.

These 2 rules will result in a request for http://yourdomain.com/mydir/?CMS_q=1&CMS_w=2&CMS_e=3&CMS_r=4 to be redirected to http://yourdomain.com/?Xq=1&Xw=2&Xe=3&Xr=4